# The Editor on Visual Studio doesn't appear

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

For some reason, whenever I open a new blank project for C++ on Visual Studio the part where you actually code doesn't appear. Whenever I open a previous project, however, everything comes up just fine. I've tried restarting, making a new project in place of the old one, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?
(I'll bet the answer is just staring me in the face, but I don't get it)

Comment: do you open a file from your project?

Comment: view->solutionexplorer  ,right click on sourcefiles->new->c++ file

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect to appear? You have no files in the blank project, so the editor does not have anything open.

To add files go to the Solution View right click and add new file. It will then open in the editor window.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a blank project, then it has no files. So I'm not sure what you expect the editor to show you.

Add a file to your project.